# Summation Formula

Tags: summation

I'm trying to do build some stats, but I don't know formulas very well. What would be the appropriate formula for this scenario:

> $1$ Person is worth $\$1$/minute.
>       Starting at $5$ People.
>       Every hour, $1$ Person is added to the group.
>       What is the total money?

So:

$(5 \times 60) + (6 \times 60) + (7 \times 60) \cdots$

If someone can write a better title or tags, I have no idea.

Edit: And I would want to know the total at say $20$ people.

Comment: You should multiply by $3600$ since there are $60\times 60$ seconds in an hour.

Comment: save money in first one hour? $5*60^2$

Comment: @kittyL Thanks for noticing that, I'll just change it to $1/minute for simplicity.

Comment: @amir I don't understand. The first hour 5 people are given 1/minute. The next hour 6 people are given 1/minute. The next hour 7 people.

Comment: See here for a tutorial on how to type math formulas on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factoring out $60$, you will get a summation
$$5+\cdots +20$$

Notice that $5+20=25, 6+19=25, \dots$. How many $25$'s can you get this way? Can you sum them up to get the result?

Comment: Sorry I accidently clicked enter when I was trying to figure out the formula. Do you know what this formula is called? Wow I can't believe I forgot all this from high school, only now do I realize how important it is.

Comment: I counted 8, which means your formula is correct. why does the formula subtract 1 from 5 in (y - x - 1) / 2 * 60? Is it because the first one wouldn't counter otherwise (the 5 people)

Comment: @JohnSmith: Because you want to find how many numbers there are among $5,6,7,\dots, 20$. We know that from $1$ to $20$ there are $20$ numbers. Now the first $4$ numbers are missing. So we subtract $4$.

Comment: Thanks, I need to think over this equation and why it works. Thanks for all your help, you were a real model stack exchange citizen!

Comment: @JohnSmith: No problem! :) The formula is possibly called summation of consecutive numbers. Or maybe there is no name.